# How to effectively add dependency .aar file in Xamarin project?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, aar, paytm

I am trying to create a Xamarin project using PayTM android library. Since PayTM doesn't have a direct Xamarin binding I have added the appinvokesdk-1.2.aar in the Xamarin Android Biding library project. The build action for appinvoke is "LibraryProjectZip". Now the appinvoke library also have a runtime dependency on easypay-8.7.3-appinvoke.aar (I found this after checking the pom file for appinvoke.aar file). I have set the build action for the easypay aar file as "EmbdedJar". I have also tried setting it to "LibraryProjectZip","ReferenceJar" and "EmbeddedReferenceJar". During runtime I am getting the error as

> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "easypay.listeners.WebClientListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.edmatix.poc.paytmdemo1-WQf3uMctjbNHoAG_ZfsH3A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.edmatix.poc.paytmdemo1-WQ…}

Here is my environment details

- Visual Studio for Mac 8.5.4 (Build 12)
- AndroidX assemblies
- Xamarin.Form 4.6.0.726
- Android Minimum API version 22
- Android Target API 28 (Android 9)

the class **easypay.listeners.WebClientListener** is only required during run time and not during compile time.

Can you please help about how to properly embed the dependency library?

Thanks

Comment: Have you already enabled multi dex support?

Comment: I don't know how to enable that. Can you please guide me?

Comment: Depends on whether you are using a Mac or Windows https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqaV3.png but open the android project settings and enable multi dex.

Comment: Hi @Saamer , My app is using minimum API version as 21. So do you still think I need multi dex?

Comment: @Saamer, I was looking at this link https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/dex-counting-xamarin-android-improved/ .First of to be clear.  I am not getting any compile time error. Also based on the link I shared, it seems, the Xamarin team have enabled some support so that we don't need multidex. Though I will still enable mulitdex and check it once

Comment: @Saamer, it does seems multidex is helping

Comment: Nice! Are you still stuck?

Comment: @Saamer, sorry, i wrote the last comment wrong. i mean to say, multidex is not helping. and yes I am still stuck

Comment: Is it not possible to integrate the existing Nuget packages that are available. You would need to share a more detailed application/build outbut

Comment: unfortunately, there is no NuGet package for the PayTM library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so this is what I did to solve the issue of missing .aar file during runtime. I added the second .aar file (easypay-8.7.3-appinvoke.aar) into another Xamarin binding project (as shown in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-an-aar)) and set the compile type as LibraryProjectZip. And that solved my issue with not finding the class in runtime.

Thanks

Comment: Hi binding for appinvokesdk-1.2.aar is find but I am getting issues for easypay-8.7.3-appinvoke.aar binding on new project. Have you done any changes in Metadata.xml?

Comment: No, not really. Actually for me the problem was there was way too many dependencies. so I moved to the PayTM integration via direct api calls. Look at the API based app invoke process in the following link https://developer.paytm.com/docs/all-in-one-sdk/

Answer (score 1):

Please try to install `Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib` in your Xamarin Android project. Installing the Kotlin package worked for me because I was using the `.aar` file which contains Kotlin code.

```
Install-Package Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib -Version 1.3.50.1
```